# How to add Jasypt decryption key for maven plugin in docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jenkins, jasypt

I have a Spring Boot project with Jasypt with maven plugin. Now the server has a Jenkins pipeline that builds a docker image and then runs.

I can run the encryption locally with maven like this:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Djasypt.encryptor.password=password
```

My question is, how do I add the jasypt encryption key in docker? Can I add it to the entrypoint or should the key be set somewhere else?

I'm a junior developer with no previous experience with DevOps and didn't set up the original pipeline, so please let me know if this should be achieved in some other way.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=staging", "/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

ENTRYPOINT ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=-Djasypt.encryptor.password=$JASYPT_KEY

Where $JASYPT_KEY is an environment variable or a key configured in your CICD tool(Jenkins or GitHub Actions)

And when you want to run this image you can use the command as below,
docker run -e JASYPT_KEY test-image

Docker is smart enough to replace the JASYPT_KEY during execution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the jaspyt key in your properties file like this

`jasypt.encryptor.password=${JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD:}`

and pass the environment variable at runtime or a key configured in your CICD tool(Jenkins, Gitlab API Token, GitHub Actions)

`-e JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=encryptor_key`